# Include Javascript in Symfony2 form widgets

Tags: javascript, forms, symfony, widget

I have created my own little Symfony2 form type. For this to work properly, I need to include a js library. While that was a simple task when using this new form type in a single web application, it became way more difficult when I decided to move that form type to a dedicated bundle in order to make it reusable.

For now, I am aware of two possible solutions

1) Ask everyone who is using my bundle to add a line into their base.html.twig

2) Add a `<script>` tag for embedding the library to my form widget

Both of them are not very smart so my question is: how do I do this better? Especially, if my form type can be included several times on a single page. And even worse, if my form type is requiring e.g. JQuery to be present, but I do not know, if JQuery has already been loaded in the application.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have any controll about where the users of your bundle actually include the JS (I know projects where they aren't included in the `::base.html.twig` file, but in a file called `layout.html.twig` in the main bundle of the application), a good way is to provide a JavaScript file which can then be included via Assetic like the following:

```
{% javascripts debug=false output="js/bundles.js"
    '@YourVendorAndBundleName/Resources/public/js/formtype.js'
%}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

So you basically just store everything you need in that one file located in `{yourBundle}/Resources/public/js`. The symfony2 command `assets:install` will do the rest.

This way the user could store your JS together with other vendor JS in one file and do more stuff with it like minifying etc.

Important: Make sure to add this to your installation/usage guide.

---

If your JS code relies on third party JS libraries like jQuery, you should not add those, as the Symfony2 Cookbook says: http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html#vendors

Instead you could require a specific asset with a specific name, like mentioned here: [Managing common javascript dependencies in Symfony 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221536/managing-common-javascript-dependencies-in-symfony-2)